# Back button position on navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently trying to develop a custom search for an iOS app.

I have managed to get the search controller appearing and the search bar appearing properly, although my only problem is that I need the back button to appear on the right of the navigation bar rather than the left, see below

(As you can see the back button is on the left but I need it to be on the right)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4UMA.jpg

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
```

class SearchTop10Controller: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self);

    self.definesPresentationContext = true;
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    //        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true;

    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit();
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    //do whatever with searchController here.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Don't edit your code to include your fixed code (without the problem). Mark the answer that got you to the solution as the answer by clicking on the check next to it.

Comment: I will say if this is something you'd like to get on the store Apple is usually pretty against going against the standard (i.e It being on the right instead of the left).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a back button to the right bar item like this:

```
let backButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back_icon"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Where `back_icon` is an image that you are using and `back` is the following function:

```
func back() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

To hide the left bar item:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

or:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how would I go about removing the left item as well ?

Comment: @Deucebigalow see edit above. You just set it to `nil`.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your help, setting to nil didn't work for hiding but using     self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true; did :) the rest seems to be working fine though, i've updated the code in the question thank you