# Navigation Controller Segue from Right to Left

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, persian

I need to change my navigation from Right to left in arabic/persian style and change the place of back button, I need totally reverse the navigation controller system I found below code on stackoverflow but I have the issue with back button :

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let src: UIViewController = self.source
        let dst: UIViewController = self.destination
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.duration = 0.25
        transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        src.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

the back button issue is that I need to put the back button on the right an when you click back button it will navigate viewcontrollers from left to right

Comment: Please describe the issue more detailed "I have the issue with back button".

Comment: huh, good point, I mentioned arabic/persian style I thought you would understand, the back button issue is that I need to put the back button on the right an when you click back button it will navigate viewcontrollers from left to right

Comment: So the question is "how to position back button as `rightNavigationBarItem`"? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38575247/1457385

Comment: it did not solve the problem, it just put the back button on right, I need to change the transition style

Comment: I need a universal solution so that I could use it through all my big project

Comment: I seem to not understand the problem. Sorry. How I understood, the transition is already working.

Comment: No I need the transition from left to right in back button